# Display loading indicator until all the images in a gallery are (fully) loaded from an API in React (using Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks, loading, indicator

I'm learning React and I'm trying to make a simple site which is basically a Giphy search engine by using their API.

So far so good I am fetching and displaying data (the trending Giphy images). The problem is that I don't like how my loading indicator works. It shows for a bit but when it disappears, the (40) images are still being populated in the container.

**Is there a way that I can make the loading indicator disappear only when everything is loaded?**

`<Loader>` is my loading indicator. I'm also using some Reactstrap components.

Here are my current 2 components:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css"
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner'
import Results from './Components/Results'
import { UncontrolledAlert } from 'reactstrap'



function App() {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [gifsData, setGifsData] = useState([])
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const giphyTrending = async () => {
            await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=OGINPHAsY1NNNhf6XIlpX1OygKXDFfXV&limit=50&rating=R`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setGifsData(data.data)
                    setLoading(false)
                })
                .catch(err => setErrorMessage(err.message))
        }
        giphyTrending()
    }, [])

    if (errorMessage) {
        return (
            <div>
                <UncontrolledAlert color="secondary">{errorMessage}</UncontrolledAlert>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            {isLoading ?
                <Loader className='loader' type="Circles" color="yellow" height={120} width={120} />
                :
                <Results isLoading={isLoading} gifsData={gifsData} />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**Results.jsx** (not sure this one is needed but just in case)

```
const Results = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='gifsContainer'>
            {props.gifsData.map(gif => (
                <div key={gif.id}>
                    <CardImg className='gifs' src={gif.images.fixed_height_small.url} alt={gif.title} />
                </div>))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115246/how-to-detect-when-a-image-is-loaded-that-is-provided-via-props-and-change-sta) it looks like you can provide an `onLoad` prop to an `img` (I'm guessing that's what you're using under the hood of `CardImg`).  If so, you can have each of those fire off a function after they're loaded, keep track of those in your parent component, and when the count of the images you received from your `fetch` match the count of the images loaded, then you can remove the loading indicator.

This is making a few assumptions.  Let me know if you'd like me to sketch out that flow for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was quite busy with other things. Your answer is helpful but I ended up using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903585/10950413 which (I think) is similar. Let me know if you find it inappropriate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link you could maintain a count in state and guarentee all images are loaded by hitting 0. So loading = loading.state and imageload.state.count != 0.

https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/

Comment: Looks interesting but couldn't make it work in functional component with hooks. That ref thing is quite advanced for my level and I couldn't convert it to work in my project. I used this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903585/10950413. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For example, we define a counter:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

At CardImage component, we use **OnLoad** function props to update counter when image is loaded completely. And while counter is not equal to **gifsData.length - 1** the IndicatorView will be displayed