# lazy loading for image in styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

```
const BackgroundImage = styled.div`
  background: url(${(props) => props.backgroundImage}) no-repeat center center;
}
```

I use `div` in style component, but it has flickering issue waiting for the image to come in. Is there any lazy loading solution using styled-component's div?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115246/how-to-detect-when-a-image-is-loaded-that-is-provided-via-props-and-change-sta

Comment: @DSteman you gave an answer on img

Comment: But you can render this component conditionally in the same way. You want to wait for `props.backgroundImage` before rendering `BackgroundImage` right?

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper around your styled component which doesn't show the `div` until the image is loaded.

You can accomplish this by creating an temporary image, wait for it to load, and then tell the component the image is ready and can be displayed.

```
const BackgroundImage = styled.div`
  background: url(${(props) => props.backgroundImage}) no-repeat center center;
`;

const LazyBackgroundImage = ({ src, children }) => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => setIsLoaded(true));
    image.src = src;
  }, [src]);

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <BackgroundImage backgroundImage={src}>
      {children}
    </BackgroundImage>
  );
};
```

Use the wrapper like this:

```
<LazyBackgroundImage src="path/to/your-image.jpg">
  <p>Hi there</p>
</LazyBackgroundImage>
```

Comment: is this line needed: `image.src = src;`?

Comment: Yes, because setting the `src` of our temporary image will start the download of the image.